# css poitioning: set sidebar width, varying content box width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make it so that the content box (Div) will automatically re-size when the browser width is changed.

The sidebar has a set width.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                Stuff
            </div>

            <div id="sidebar">
                Text<br/>Sidebar
            </div>

            <div id="content">
                Stuff<br/>text<br/>Just to fill some space
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                Stuff
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
#wrapper{
    width:90%;
}
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
#content{
    /* *** I want something that will change width to fill blank space when the user re-sizes the browser and the sidebar moves *** */
    margin-top:4px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#sidebar{
    width:100px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:4px;
    background-color:pink;
}
#footer{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    margin-top:4px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Note that this is just code I wrote while writing this question. All I done was missed out extra code that is irrelevant to the question.

This should (Not tested) show a header at the top, and a footer at the bottom.

The part that I need help with is the middle section.

When the browser width gets changed (Smaller of bigger), the sidebar will stay to the right.

I want the "#content" box to automatically re-size so that there is a gap in between the "#content" box and the "#footer" box.

I have tried css width % values but that doesn't work.

Can css do this?

If not, can I get any php or javascript that can do that?

Comment: Just give `#content` a `margin-right` of `100px` or `104px` if you want a `4px` gap. http://jsfiddle.net/urEbY/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `overflow: hidden` to #content. this makes it use the "rest" of the width, browser-width minus 100px for the sidebar.

if you want to have an extra gab between the sidebar and your actual content, add the following to #content:

box-sizing: border-box;
padding-right: 20px; /* (or whatever)*/

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/urEbY/1/

Comment: This won't give a gap between the sidebar and the content.

Comment: give it a try. it just hides content outside of #content which is a common habbit combined with float (used for multi-column-layouts). it doesn't hide the contnt inside it! and it will defenitely make a gap between the content inside #content (not seen with the yellow background as the space is inside of #content! no need for downvote without a try

Comment: Ok, I see where you're coming from now. But if the asker has a different `background-color` for his `#content div`, you'll run into problems with this method.

Comment: then you add an extra div and do the same for that... I just don't like hardcoding all those values as I am doing a lot of responsive stuff. I the width of the sidebar changes, you would always need to change the margin too. But in the end, both ways solve the same problem, both solutions are correct :)

Comment: Thank you, in theory, the padding-right should work, and it does. I adding a "margin-left:4px;" in the "#sidebar" on the jasfiddle and it did the effect "gap" I wanted in between the sidebar and the content box. However, it leaves me with another 2 problems... first, the sidebar height doesn't match the content box, and also the content box (the yellow box) on my actual website (is lightblue) doesn't cut off the right bit like it did on jsfiddle. If anyone could help me identify the problem it would be very appreciated. (http://rikahiyuka.com/)

Comment: 1. both elements having the same height: use a construct with display: table or a "fake background" simulating the backround colors on an surrounding element. but both need a different markup and are a differnt problem than this one. 2. what do you mean by "cut off the right bit"?

Comment: Sorry, by "cut off right bit" I mean that the content box does not extend its background under the sidebar, but on my website, it still extends under the sidebar.

Comment: Opps, sorry again, my brain rewired is working again. I have found the problem. I have used padding (affects content inside content box) instead of the right margin. (X_X)

Comment: this is because your DivC has no overflow: hidden as I suggested. As soon as you really use the answer you accepted it will work :)

Answer (score 1):

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/fQPse/

**HTML** (that you need to ammend) :

```
 <div id="content">
                <p> <!-- add a paragrap -->
                       Stuff<br/>text<br/>Just to fill some space
                </p>
            </div>
```

**CSS** (that you need to ammend) :

```
#content >p {margin-right:100px;margin-top:0px}
```

Comment: Adding a paragraph is good practice. The yellow `div` will still appear behind and below the side panel, but perhaps that's what the asker wants. +1

Comment: adding a paragraph is defenitely but mostely you have more content than just ONE paragraph. and adding margin-right to all of them is quite aweful, isn't it?

Comment: @RiaElliger : please note that there is a 100px sidebar in the right to the `content`...you wont like your `p` to overlap with the sidebar...would u mate??? :)

Comment: definitely not. I just say that if you have a p, an image, a list, a table or whatever inside #content, you would have to add margin-right:100px; to all of them with your method. you can't put them inside a p but would have to add them next to it :)

Comment: Add a `div` inside `#content` with `margin-left: 100px` to avoid having to do it for multiple elements.

Comment: @RiaElliger haha..good one mate, but in that case, adding that `margin` to straight `#content` div should solve it...http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/fQPse/1/ or what gaynorvader suggested :)

Comment: or add overflow: hidden without being interested in how wide the sidebar actually is :) so you can change it whenever you want and #content always takes the rest ;)